# Microsoft Dynamics 365 API How to Retrieve data from 2 custom entities with foreign key?

Tags: api, postman, microsoft-dynamics

I have 2 custom entities (linked together with a foreign key) in Microsoft dynamics CRM and i would like to retrieve data with the API using POSTMAN

```
society/api/data/v9.1/entity1?$select=data1,data2,data3&$expand=foreignkeyentity2
```

My GET request works but I have a `@odata.nextLink` response instead of the foreign key values

I saw in the Microsoft docs a note that said:

*If you expand on collection-valued navigation parameters to retrieve related entities for entity sets, a @odata.nextLink property will be returned instead for the related entities. You should use the value of the @odata.nextLink property with a new GET request to return the required data. More information:Retrieve related tables by expanding navigation properties*

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/developer/data-platform/webapi/query-data-web-api#bkmk_expandRelated

But when I follow the instructions from the docs, I get another `@odata.context` value which leads me to a 50000000 line page with values I don't understand

Comment: can I suggest to use my tool Dataverse REST Builder https://github.com/GuidoPreite/DRB? It will allow you to build the request with your actual metadata (and you can expand the relationships too). Not all requests return an odata nextlink, and if the odata nextlink is returned there is also a specific message to execute it (you can also export the requests to Postman)

Comment: Hello, thanks for the suggestion, I don't understand the odata nextlink value that the API returned, i tried a GET request with it and got another link that leads to a giant page with 50000000 line of property name etc like HTML tag.. 
I don't understand on how to use it

Comment: the odata nextlink is just the address containing the query settings to see the related records in your case, for this is important to select just the properties you want to retrieve inside the expand part (the one linking the realtionship) otherwise you will probably get all the columns

Comment: even by filtering only 1 column the odata nexlink retrieves me 1 page of 150k lines not exact values i want.. also i can't seem to find anything on the microsoft docs.. anyway thanks for your help

Comment: can you post a screenshot (and hiding personal information) of these lines you are getting? just to understand which kind of response you are receiving. thanks

Comment: https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=22/05/9xtw.png

Comment: from the screenshot looks like you got a metadata response (the one you can get from the url https://yourinstance.crm.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.0/$metadata) are you sure you are fetching the odata nextlink? can you do a screenshot of the property you are getting from the first odata call and the url content of that property?

Comment: the screenshot was the url that i got(in the @odata.context) after fetching the first @odata.nextlink

Comment: inside your screenshot I can see only the content, not the url called

Comment: https://myinstance.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v9.1/$metadata#incidents(severitycode) was the url i called that i recieve

Comment: that is not a url you will receive inside the odata nextlink, that is usually the link you see inside the main response as first entry, the odata nextlink will appear inside the main object